# save text chat in the server with architecture of webrtc+socket.io+nodejs

Tags: socket.io, chat, webrtc

I am building a chat system where I am using webrtc and socket.io + node js for building the system. My problem is how to put back up of text chats on my server while there is 1-o-1 chat.

Approach one could be using webrtc for the chat that is peer to peer communication and with every successful message sent I would hit a web service through Which I could update the db. But this seems to me not a good approach as I have to update db from client everytime and network bandwidth seems to be an issue specially for mobile clients.

Another approach could be sending the messages through socket.io and from the node js server save the chat in db from node js server.

Second approach makes more sense to me but I am looking for the best approach.

Comment: If you want a server to be involved in this chat (for storage), then using P2P at all doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

When I wrote my chat application (using socket.io), persisting chat history was done on the socket.io server side

i.e.

```
socket.on('chat:message', function(message){

    //persist message to db here

    io.emit('chat:message', message);

});
```

it worked fine for me